# What causes Lorentzian broadening of X-ray diffraction peaks?

Tags: diffraction, statistics, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

In X-ray diffraction, the pseudo-Voigt model is a combination of Gaussian and Lorentzian distributions, and is often used to model peaks. The form of the peak is often described as

$V(x)$ = (1-$\alpha$)$G(x)$ + $\alpha$$L(x)$

G(x) and L(x) are the gaussian and Lorentzian parts.

What is the physical significance of $\alpha$?

Are the mechanisms that cause Lorentzian broadening different than those causing Gaussian?

Comment: The Lorentzian may be attributed to the lifetime broadening of the characteristic x-ray emission line.

Comment: @Pieter: Do you mean that Lorentzian broadening could be due to the x-ray source? The source and the system setup will definitely cause broadening of the peaks. Is that normally Lorentzian?

Comment: Yes, if the source is a characteristic x-ray emission line that is not strongly monochromatized, the lifetime of that core-hole state in the source will affect the width of diffraction peaks. Lifetime broadening gives a lorentzian in the energy distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid $\alpha$ has no physical meaning here.

The line profile (i.e. the profile of the diffraction peak) is a convolution of the instrument and physical broadening. The latter means broadening caused by the microstructure of the sample, which is typically divided into the size and strain components. (keyword: size-strain analysis)

But all the components above can contribute to both Gaussian and Lorentzian parts, so it's not like in spectroscopy that you can assign physical meaning to each part. Here Pseudo-Voigt (or Voigt or Pearson VII) is just an empirical shape.